# Wireless site survey for AP placement

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-access-point, ubiquiti

How do you do a wireless site survey to plan AP placement?

My understanding is that you set up the APs, measure the signal strength multiple times in every room, spaced by test resolution, and then move the APs and repeat.

Is there a better way to do it that's less trial-and-error? I'm sure professionals can look at the building and use their experience to come up with more efficient AP test locations, but I can't.

Comment: Tamosoft Site Survey  www.tamos.com

Comment: Does that remove the trial and error? It looks like that software still requires you to place the APs, take data, place APs somewhere else, take more data, etc.

Comment: Site surveys normally require trial an error for AP placement to get best results.